# Obtaining a closed form for a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem

In the middle of a problem, I faced to the following series,
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=0}^{j-1} {j-i+k-1 \choose k-1}  \left(\frac{a}{x+y}\right)^i \left(\frac{y-a}{x+y}\right)^{j-i}
\end{eqnarray}
I thought I could use Binomial theorem to find a closed form for it, but because of ${j-i+k-1 \choose k-1}$, I could not do it. Anyone could give me a clue that whether I can go further or not and how?

Comment: Substituting $m=j-i$ and some algebra we get the expression $\left(\frac{a}{x+y}\right)^{j}\sum_{m=1}^{j}{\binom{m+k-1}{k-1}\left(\frac{y-a}{a}\right)^{m}}$

Comment: Are you familair with the gaussian hypergeometric function ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No, I have not heard it. Is it useful for this problem? I will google it to see how I can apply it here. Thanks

Comment: Just wait until you learn about them. In any manner, it is a closed form formula.... which hides a summation.